# How to make MS Bot Framework on Node.js wait for the user's next message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework

I am trying to write my first bot using Node.js and MS Bot Framework. From the examples provided by Microsoft, I can't figure out how to achieve this scenario:

1. Bot sends a message to the user.
2. Bot waits for the user's answer.
3. Bot runs another function to process this answer.

The examples have this code:

```
        if (!item.size) {
            // Prompt for size
            builder.Prompts.choice(session, "What size would you like?", "Small|Medium|Large|Extra Large");
        } else {
            //Skip to next waterfall step
            next();
        }
```

The first method (`builder.Prompts.choice()`) achieves what I want, but I don't want to use the ugly built-in prompts. I'd rather just do it manually (send message to user, offer options, wait for response).

The second method (`next()`) just skips to the next step without waiting for the user's input.

I have a dialog created like this:

```
bot.dialog('name', [function 1() {}, function 2() {}]);
```

So I just want to find a way so that `function 1` outputs a message and waits for the user input, then moves on to `function 2`.

Comment: In c# sdk this is : context.Wait(nextMethod);. You should find something similar for node.js.
Maybe you can get user input and send it to another function where you can control your Dialog ?

Comment: I know that, and there's nothing similar in Node because the dialog logic is not in any way similar to C#.

Comment: Why don't you use another function to handle user input ?

Comment: Which one? @BobSwager

Comment: Create Dialog, expect user input, handle user input in a function, when you're done just end that DIalog.

Comment: @BobSwager That's exactly what I am asking! How do you "expect user input"? I would love if there was a function like `bot.wait_for_user_input_and_then_continue()`, just like in Bot Framework for C#, but I don't see any.

Answer (score 2):

Is the builder.Prompts.text() a solution for your scenario?

You can just give a question (string text) with it, and the user can reply with whatever he wants.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-prompt

Comment: In his question he says "but I don't want to use the ugly built-in prompts"